# Sumbodule strategy to be used with "fetch" git strategy

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, git-submodules

I try `GIT_STRATEGY: fetch` and it works fine - reuses code from the previous job. The problem there is no corresponding value for `GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY` in docs. If I use `recursive` it will always download submodules. If I set `none` it would not create submodules in case of empty image, according to docs. How to tell "init sumbodules recursively if they don't exist only" ?

Answer (score 0):

By default the git submodule update --recursive only updates the submodules if they don't already exist. In your case I'd do something like:

```
job:
  variables:
    GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
    GIT_SUBMOUDLE_UPDATE_FLAGS: --init
  script:
    -ls -al .git/modules/
```

This job log should output the following:
git submodule update --init --recursive

Comment: In the original test (without `--init` but with `recursive`) it always updated the submodules in second etc. runs. At least according to  log records it traversed all submodule directories so that there is no visible difference with the first run.

Comment: It'll always traverse down to verify the commit hash for each submodule is the same as the actual repo, but if they are the same it won't download any new code.